# How to fix vite warning: The JSX import source cannot be set?

Tags: reactjs, vite, emotion

I'm running a react app with vite using emotion css. In order to use the css attritbute of emotions on html-elements I need to set a special comment to enable a vite build:

```
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */
import { css, jsx } from "@emotion/react"
```

It used to work fine but now I get the following warning and I don't know what it means and how to fix it:

```
[vite] warning: The JSX import source cannot be set without also enabling React's "automatic" JSX transform
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this into your `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react",
    ...
  },
}
```

Source: https://emotion.sh/docs/typescript#emotionreact